# changing all colors to Black/White using minted.sty

Tags: minted

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{default}
\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[]{python}
saying = "It's turtles all the way down"
\end{minted}

\usemintedstyle{bw}

\begin{minted}[]{python}
saying = "It's turtles all the way down"
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

**Output**
[image]

In the second list, I need to change `all colors to B/W`, but the text was changed to `italic style`, how can I change just the colors only? Please suggest....

Comment: If you don't want colored listings at all us the `listings` package.

Comment: Have you tried the `text` lexer instead of `python` (`\begin{minted}{text}`)? That would eliminate all highlighting.

Comment: You want only two colors black and white, or you want a gray scale colorspace?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ I need only two colors B/W...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get black-and-white style variant, this attempt locally disables color command.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\newcommand{\mintedStyleBw}{%
  \renewcommand\fcolorbox[3][]{##3}%
  \renewcommand\textcolor[3][]{##3}%
}

\makeatletter
% let minted accept fancyvrb option "formatcom*"
\minted@def@optfv{formatcom*}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\subsection*{Colorful \texttt{minted} output}
\begin{minted}{python}
saying = "It's turtles all the way down" # comment
a = 1 + 3 + len(list())
\end{minted}

inline: \mintinline{python}|saying = "It's turtles all the way down" # comment|


\subsection*{Black and white \texttt{minted} output}
\begin{minted}[formatcom*=\mintedStyleBw]{python}
saying = "It's turtles all the way down" # comment
a = 1 + 3 + len(list())
\end{minted}

inline: \mintinline[formatcom*=\mintedStyleBw]{python}|saying = "It's turtles all the way down" # comment|
\end{document}
```

[image]

In addition, a new `minted` option, say `bwstyle`, can be defined to toggle the black-and-white (sub)style. This makes the user interface clearer.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\minted@style@bw}{%
  \renewcommand\fcolorbox[3][]{##3}%
  \renewcommand\textcolor[3][]{##3}%
}

% define new minted option "bwstyle"
\minted@def@opt@switch{bwstyle}
\fvset{formatcom*={%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\minted@get@opt{bwstyle}{true}}{true}}
  {\minted@style@bw}{}%
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\subsection*{Colorful \texttt{minted} output}
\begin{minted}{python}
saying = "It's turtles all the way down" # comment
a = 1 + 3 + len(list())
\end{minted}

inline: \mintinline{python}|saying = "It's turtles all the way down" # comment|


\subsection*{Black and white \texttt{minted} output}
\begin{minted}[bwstyle]{python}
saying = "It's turtles all the way down" # comment
a = 1 + 3 + len(list())
\end{minted}

inline: \mintinline[bwstyle]{python}|saying = "It's turtles all the way down" # comment|
\end{document}
```

Some notes:

- The colors used in a `Pygments` style is hard-coded in python source code, and finally converted to `\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.73,0.73}{...}` in the `.pygstyle` file.
- Compared to modifying python or `\PYG@xxx` tex styling code, disabling color commands requires less effort.
- At first this answer uses `fancyvrb` option `codes*` to insert color command patches. But different to `fancyvrb`, `fvextra` restricted scope of `code*`, which is designed to accept catcode changes only (then stored in `\FancyVerbCodes`), to tokenization step, hence makes `\mintinline`, `\Verb` and `VerbEnv` environment ignores `\FancyVerbCodes` at typesetting step.  Now another option `formatcom*` is used, which works for `\inlinemint` as well.
  Reported to `fvextra`, see https://github.com/gpoore/fvextra/issues/17.

Comment: Its awesome...thanks a lot...

Comment: What can I do to make the above also works for \mintinline ? For me, I'd like inline code to be black.

Comment: @PyiSoe See updated answer. By using `formatcom*` option, now it works for both `{minted}` and `\minteinline`.

Comment: Oh, very kind. Thanks a lot.